# Calling function after pressing button crashes app

Tags: java, android

this is my first time asking a question here and I'm pretty new to Android app programming. What I have is a button that when pressed, reads the file stored on the phone with reading_wav(). However, my app stops responding after i press the button. I know the function works as I've tested it on a separate java project. 
Thanks

```
public class CheckWavFiles2 extends ActionBarActivity {// No runnable

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.check_wav2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_check_wav2,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

private static final String LOG_TAG = "CheckWavFiles2";
private static String mFileName = null;
int i = 0;

private NormalButton mNormalButton = null;

class NormalButton extends Button {
    String mClassifyNormal = "Normal.wav";
    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setText("Normal.wav");
            onNormal(mClassifyNormal);
        }
    };

    public NormalButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Normal.wav");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

private void onNormal(String fName) {
    if (fName == "Normal.wav") {
        readNormal();
    } else {

    }
}

private void readNormal() {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            reading_wav sampleReader = null;

            try {
                sampleReader = new reading_wav(new File(mFileName));
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }.start();

}

public CheckWavFiles2() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.wav";
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    mNormalButton = new NormalButton(this);
    ll.addView(mNormalButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
    setContentView(ll);
}

}
```

Logcat output:

```
    12-07 01:47:03.261: D/libEGL(20770): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-07 01:47:03.276: D/libEGL(20770): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-07 01:47:03.281: D/libEGL(20770): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-07 01:47:03.291: E/(20770): Device driver API match
12-07 01:47:03.291: E/(20770): Device driver API version: 20
12-07 01:47:03.291: E/(20770): User space API version: 20 
12-07 01:47:03.291: E/(20770): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel2 BUILD_DATE=Mon Sep  2 14:16:28 KST 2013 
12-07 01:47:03.311: D/OpenGLRenderer(20770): Enabling debug mode 0
12-07 01:47:13.261: W/dalvikvm(20770): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1301 (Ljavax/sound/sampled/UnsupportedAudioFileException;)
12-07 01:47:13.261: W/dalvikvm(20770): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x11
12-07 01:47:13.261: W/dalvikvm(20770): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/stethoscope2/CheckWavFiles2$1;.run ()V
12-07 01:47:13.261: W/dalvikvm(20770): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0011
12-07 01:47:13.261: W/dalvikvm(20770): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/stethoscope2/CheckWavFiles2$1;.run ()V
12-07 01:47:13.261: W/dalvikvm(20770): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/stethoscope2/CheckWavFiles2$1;
12-07 01:47:13.261: D/AndroidRuntime(20770): Shutting down VM
12-07 01:47:13.261: W/dalvikvm(20770): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a24930)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770): java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/stethoscope2/CheckWavFiles2$1
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at com.example.stethoscope2.CheckWavFiles2.readNormal(CheckWavFiles2.java:94)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at com.example.stethoscope2.CheckWavFiles2.onNormal(CheckWavFiles2.java:84)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at com.example.stethoscope2.CheckWavFiles2.access$0(CheckWavFiles2.java:82)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at com.example.stethoscope2.CheckWavFiles2$NormalButton$1.onClick(CheckWavFiles2.java:71)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18370)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
12-07 01:47:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(20770):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 01:47:13.296: D/dalvikvm(20770): GC_CONCURRENT freed 153K, 16% free 7779K/9172K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 30ms
12-07 01:47:17.156: D/libEGL(21211): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-07 01:47:17.171: D/libEGL(21211): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-07 01:47:17.176: D/libEGL(21211): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-07 01:47:17.176: E/(21211): Device driver API match
12-07 01:47:17.176: E/(21211): Device driver API version: 20
12-07 01:47:17.176: E/(21211): User space API version: 20 
12-07 01:47:17.176: E/(21211): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel2 BUILD_DATE=Mon Sep  2 14:16:28 KST 2013 
12-07 01:47:17.206: D/OpenGLRenderer(21211): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: What exception is thrown? You can use logcat to view any exceptions that occur, helping you debug the issue.

Comment: Like Mr. Zorn said, the first thing you should do here is to include a stack trace (the error you receive in your LogCat window in your IDE). Another thing is that opening a file (or any storage I/O for that matter), should be done in an AsyncTask. You don't want to be blocking the UI thread on opening a file.

Comment: Ok I added the logcat. And thanks, meanwhile I'll look how AsyncTask works.

Answer (score 0):

some android versions doesn't include all the Java supported methods, So the problem here is that you are using some method in your method `CheckWavFiles2()` this method is supported by **Java** but not supported by the sdk level you are using for **android**, So, if for example you are using `android-sdk13`(exists in `manifest.xml` file) as your min sdk, try use `android-sdk20` and then run your app and I think it will work then.

And before that, I think the problem is in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`

So, try instead:

```
File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/audiorecordtest.wav");
mFileName = mPath.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: My targetSdkVersion was 21 though. I did change the way to get the file path though, but that didn't do it